# Can I change the apps view based on if a file has been saved?

Tags: iphone

Please help! I'm a newbie to programming and I'm having the following trouble. I am trying to write my first iphone app and I would like it to do the following.

When the app launches user enters name, presses button and goes to new view. Their name is saved to file and used through out the app. That much I have managed.

I would like the app to check to see if there is a saved file when it is launched and go directly to second view instead of the first view. I'm have search for days looking for an answer and I'm still not sure how to do this.

At the risk of seeming stupid do I use an IF statement and how do I write it. Please help.

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: You should take a look at NSUserDefaults for storing such simple key value information, it is a lot easier to use than writing to a file (and has some other useful functions that come "free").

Answer (score 1):

You have to use NSUserDefaults for storing the user name and pass words. If you want to store more data's, have to use plist(Documents Directory) or core data or SQLite.

```
// Store the data 

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"yourPasswordString" forKey:@"YourKey"];


// Retrieve the data

NSString *passWord = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"YourKey"];
```

Once you retrieved the data, you have to check the conditions like,

```
 if(passWord == nil)
 {
      //load first view
 }
 else
{
     // load second view
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much for the help however I don't know what to do with this code. Were do I put it. I have tried putting it in my .m file and I get the following errors.   "Expected identifier or '(' before '[' default   and "initializer" element is not constant

Comment: It should be used in .m class files, first you should store the data(your email string), after that you will retrieve the string from any classes.

Comment: Please Help! NSUserDefaults is not saving the file.      
-(IBAction)LogInButton:(id)sender {
 NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 [prefs setObject:Name forKey:@"UserName"];
 [prefs synchronize];
 
 if (Name == nil) {
  ClubSearchViewController *CSearch = [[ClubSearchViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ClubSearchViewController" bundle:Nil];
  [self presentModalViewController:CSearch animated:YES];
 }
 else {
SearchMenu *SMenu = [[SearchMenu alloc]initWithNibName:@"SearchMenu" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:SMenu animated:YES];
 }
}  @Pugal Devan

Answer (score 0):

if you're using NSUserDefaults to save it then all you have to do is try reading the value into a string, then check if it is nil, if it is, then the files isn't there and you would load your first view, if it was, then load your second view.

```
NSString *tempStr = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"yourKey"];

if(tempStr == nil)
{
    //load your first view
}
else
{
    // load your second view
}
```

You need to read your key back out in order to test if it is nil, the way you are doing this, you will never be nil and will always use the else choice, you need to set your object elsewhere, probably in the if statement.

```
-(IBAction)LogInButton:(id)sender 
{
    NSString *tempStr = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"UserName"];

    if (tempStr == nil || [tempStr isEqualToString:""]) 
    {
         NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; 
        [prefs setObject:Name.text forKey:@"UserName"]; 
        [prefs synchronize];

        ClubSearchViewController *CSearch = [[ClubSearchViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ClubSearchViewController" bundle:Nil]; 
        [self presentModalViewController:CSearch animated:YES]; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        SearchMenu *SMenu = [[SearchMenu alloc]initWithNibName:@"SearchMenu" bundle:nil]; 
        [self presentModalViewController:SMenu animated:YES];
    }
}

-(IBAction)LogOutButton:(id)sender
{
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; 
    [prefs setObject:@"" forKey:@"UserName"]; 
    [prefs synchronize];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help however I don't know what to do with this code. Were do I put it. I have tried putting it in my .m file and I get the following errors. "Expected identifier or '(' before '[' default and "initializer" element is not constan

Comment: You would put this in your .m file, can you post what you have written?

Comment: Please Help! NSUserDefaults is not saving the file. -(IBAction)LogInButton:(id)sender { NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; [prefs setObject:Name forKey:@"UserName"]; [prefs synchronize]; if (Name == nil) { ClubSearchViewController *CSearch = [[ClubSearchViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ClubSearchViewController" bundle:Nil]; [self presentModalViewController:CSearch animated:YES]; } else { SearchMenu *SMenu = [[SearchMenu alloc]initWithNibName:@"SearchMenu" bundle:nil]; [self presentModalViewController:SMenu animated:YES]; } } @IanOswald

Comment: This will only work for one username, if you want to check others, you will have to have a logged out flag somewhere as well so that you can blank out your user name in which case you'll also have to check for an empty username eg (if([tempStr isEqualToString:@""]){ show first view.})

Comment: Hi again. I have progress however the file is still not saving and the app does not move past the first if condition. The console shows the following.   -[NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey:]: Attempt to insert non-property value '<UITextField: 0x4b17640; frame = (20 49; 280 31); text = 'wayne'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x4b17750>>' of class 'UITextField'.   Thank you so much for your help with this could I trouble you again with this.@IanOswald

Comment: You can't add a uitextfield to NSUserDefaults, you have to add the text from the text field.  I have edited my response accordingly.